# Can I open a Google Slides doc in read-only mode?

Tags: google-slides

I want to view the file, but don't want to accidentally change it. See [this similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94633/can-i-open-a-google-drive-document-in-read-only-mode).

I think this feature should be available in all Google Docs files, but it currently is not. Is there a workaround? If not, I would also like to hear  your opinions in the comment section, because I think the feature is important.

Comment: I've the same question. The best workaround for me is the preview mode (solution #1 from here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117663/87455)